# Реализовать иерархию классов

Tags: java, ооп

подскажите как можно сделать иерархическую структуру(класс Подразделение) не могу сделать этот класс уже несколько день не понимаю.. помогите язык java.
Есть 4 классы – «Человек», «Сотрудник», «Подразделение», «Должность». Классы 'подразделения' должны иметь иерархическую структуру, то есть каждое подразделение может иметь главное и подчиненные подразделение. Должны быть доступны ввод/вывод подразделения организации.

Comment: вы хотя бы попытайтесь, без примера кода, с конкретным вопросом что именно у вас не получается никто вам помогать не станет.

Comment: спасибо, изменил вопрос

Comment: держи, лентяй, тебе набросок https://pastebin.com/iDx8ZjLv подправь, т.к. что имелось в виду под вводом/выводом подразделений и какие еще где поля быть должны не понятно из описания номер 2, а первое я наизусть не запомнил. но как пример про наследование думаю тебе хватит.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: извините я новичок, хотел спросить что нужно подправить а то не понимаю

Comment: ну добавить недостающие поля. добавить сотрудников к подразделениям, или наоборот, из описания ж не понятно кого куда.

Comment: спасибо я подправил как надо